# RegEx match string with variable character

Tags: regex

I have a string like so

```
<image id="1347292584243" x="377" y="217" width="304" height="110" 
   xmlns:NS1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   NS1:href="../../bpdocs/docs/ded98560-61d0-42f2-944e-30280d54e94b/xskykg886745dsv8998e8fd5k668mz/images/w/a31ab754-22ce-43a6-be00-a374b4a8c87a.jpg"
   xmlns:NS2="" NS2:xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" bpw="304" bph="110" />
```

Within this string, I would like to match the following individual strings

1. xmlns:NS1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
2. xmlns:NS2=""
3. NS2:xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

I'd like to match the above however in each part of these strings contains NS[x]. where x = variable number

Could someone provide me with an expression to match something like this?

Thanks

Comment: So in case of 1, 2 and 3 you want to know whether its NS1 or NS2?
Will the initial string always contain 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: No, the number is variable as in it could be any integer

Comment: I am using XDocument in c# but it won't parse because it contains these invalid namespaces so i'm trying to remove them before I parse.

Comment: unmarshalling xml with an appropriate library would be less painful and error prone.

Comment: How would I go about doing that in c#? I just need an xml parser that doesn't fall over with invalid xml!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work?

```
\S*NS\d+\S*
```

It means sequence of non-spaces (`\S*`), then `NS`, then one or more digits (`\d+`), then another sequence of non-spaces (`\S*`).